# going back to basics - Instantiating classes

Tags: ruby

Trying to understand instantiating better. I created a problem for myself, which i hope makes sense.

There are 2 files: `test.rb` and `length.rb`.

In `test.rb`, I want to create a box, and specify it's length, then print out it's length using "puts".

`length.rb` is where the instance variable length is created. I want to store the data there. I'm not sure if my understanding of it is right, but that's what i gathered from my back end course...

So here are the codes. Many thanks in advance.

Edit: sorry, the question is, how do i get the last code to run?

the puts "the lenth of the rectangle is ---whatever length i input into the function/method"

```
# test.rb

require "./length.rb"

    def createLength
        puts "What is the length of the box?"
        length = gets.strip

        BoxLength.new( length )
    end

    box_one = createLength

    puts "the length of box_one is #{box_one.length}"


# length.rb

require "./test.rb"

    class BoxLength

        attr_accessor :length

        def initialize( length )
            @length = length
        end

    end
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: why does length.rb `require "./test.rb"`?

Comment: And the code runs fine for me. What happens in your case?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question you need to post 3 things:

1. Your code (or a small program that demonstrates the problem in your real code).
2. The expected output.
3. The actual output.

1-2-3. Live it, love it. learn it.

The `require ./test.rb` line is unnecessary--inside the file length.rb, you aren't using any code in test.rb.

> I want to store the data [in length.rb].

You aren't storing any data in `length.rb`.  `length.rb` contains the definition of a class.  In `test.rb`, you are importing that class definition, then in `test.rb` you are creating an instance of that class, and then you are initializing its one instance variable with a value. After `test.rb` finishes executing, your instance is destroyed along with the data.

> I want to store the data there. I'm not sure if my understanding of it
>   is right, but that's what i gathered from my ***back end course***

***Back end*** implies some type of database, and a simple file an be used as a database.  You can write values to a file, then retrieve the values later:

square_box.rb:

```
class SquareBox
  attr_accessor :side

  def initialize(side)
    @side = side
  end

  def area
    side ** 3
  end

end
```

test.rb:

```
require './square_box'

File.open('mydata.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts('5')
end

def create_box
  side = nil

  File.open('mydata.txt') do |f|
    side = f.gets.to_i
  end

  SquareBox.new(side) 
end

my_box = create_box
puts "The side of my_box is: #{my_box.side}"
puts "The area of my_box is: #{my_box.area}"

--output:--
The side of my_box is: 5
The area of my_box is: 125
```

Or:

square_box.rb:

```
class SquareBox
  attr_accessor :side

  def initialize(side)
    @side = side

    File.open('mydata.txt', 'a') do |f|
      f.puts side
    end
  end

  def area
    side ** 3
  end

end
```

test.rb:

```
require './square_box'

def get_side
  print "What is a side for your square box? "
  gets.to_i
end

my_box = SquareBox.new(get_side)

puts "The side of my_box is: #{my_box.side}"
puts "The area of my_box is: #{my_box.area}"

another_box = SquareBox.new(get_side)

def print_report
  puts "The SquareBoxes created so far have sides of length:"

  IO.foreach('mydata.txt') do |line|
    puts "\t#{line}"
  end
end

print_report

--output:--
~/ruby_programs$ ruby test.rb 
What is a side for your square box? 10
The side of my_box is: 10
The area of my_box is: 1000
What is a side for your square box? 5
The SquareBoxes created so far have sides of length:
    10
    5
```

Finally, ruby indenting is 2 spaces--not 4 spaces, not 5 spaces, not 1 space.  Two spaces.

Comment: Maybe you're taking OP a bit too literal (concerning "back end")?